# Sql: Extract records with some condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have rows in Oracle database table (having +2M records) and I want to extract records with some condition. The constraint is not setup on the table. Any help will be appreciated.

```
nif                 num_sum
--------------------------
123                   456
123                   456
123                   789   // => I want to select this
134                   600
```

Records having a `nif` with one or more same `num_sum` is allowed. But if a `nif` exists for two or more different `num_sum`s, I want to select that `nif` and `num_sum`. I showed the above records for explanation only.

I tried:

```
select distinct nif, num_sum
from sumcon
group by nif, num_sum
having count(distinct nif) > 1
```

Comment: Can you add the row (200, 789) too, and adjust the result?

Comment: @jarlh it's large production DB, I can't just add records

Comment: Your table has only 3 rows, I wouldn't call that a large db...

Comment: @jarlh I showed 3 records for reference only...

Comment: And I meant you should add the row (200, 789) to the sample data, and adjust the result, if needed. (You don't have to insert into the production db.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your description,

"Records having a nif with one or more same num_sum is allowed (a nif shouldn't be for two different num_sums)"

I think you want the following:

```
SELECT nif
  FROM sumcon
 GROUP BY nif
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT num_sum) > 1;
```

First, in your original query `DISTINCT` is superfluous. Next, since you say there should not exist more than one distinct value of `num_sum` for a given value of `nif`, I think you want to group by `nif` and use `COUNT(DISTINCT num_sum)`. Now if you mean that a given value of `num_sum` should not exist for more than one unique value of `nif`, then you would want the following:

```
SELECT num_sum
  FROM sumcon
 GROUP BY num_sum
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT nif) > 1;
```

If you need to get all the values of `nif` for which this is the case, then you would have to do something like this:

```
SELECT nif, num_sum FROM sumcon
 WHERE num_sum IN (
    SELECT num_sum
      FROM sumcon
     GROUP BY num_sum
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT nif) > 1
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that was what I want and will check later. I'm on GMT+3

Answer (score 1):

You don't return any records because there's only 1 distinct value for `nif`, so the count is not greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it's exactly what you asked for, but i hope it will help you.

```
select nif, num_sum from sumcon group by nif, num_sum having count(1) > 1
```

Comment: Why would one use `COUNT(1)`?